# How many level can mongodb append sub-documents dynamicaly?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

It seems that i can go further than one `subdocument` if i want to add it **dynamicaly**, here is the code:

```
db.users.update({"pup.cmn.id":id}, {"$addToSet":{"pup.cmn":{"abus":email}}})
```

this give error:

```
OperationFailure: can't append to array using string field name: cmn
```

then, if i add `positional element` i get this:

```
db.users.update({"pup.cmn.id":id}, {"$addToSet":{"pup.$.cmn":{"abus":email}}}) 

"cmn" : 
[ 
{ 
"fto" : ObjectId("5190e8a53a5f3a0c102af045") 
"id" : "14.05.2013 12:29:53" 
},
{ 
"abus" : "u...@example.com" 
}
]
```

so as you can see, it will add it in the same level, and i dont want that, because the application will get errors.

Comment: Would you update your question with the original document and a sample of the result you want?

Comment: what i want is just put `abus` under `cmn` and not in the same level

Comment: From your example, that's what it appears is happening.

Comment: yes, it is added in the same level and not under it :(

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question. cmn is an array, if you add something to it it will be in the array. OR do you want to add abus to the first element of the array? Create a sample doc of what you expect this will help us give you a correct answer :)

Comment: @Marc what i wanted to do, is adding a sub-document dynamically, and it seems it is not possible on mongodb for now, look here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Mongodb for the time of writing (2.4.x) have not this feature, there is a ticket:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831